# Why is play framework not running my evolutions?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, playframework-evolutions

I recently started a new project, based from the [scala-play-react-seed](https://github.com/yohangz/scala-play-react-seed/).

I have a little experience with Play and have other projects that use play-slick and slick-evolutions - everything works fine and the evolutions are recognised and applied at startup.

In the new project, this isn't happening. My connection to the database is all OK so that's not the issue.

I don't get any errors or warnings about the evolutions, as far as I can see.

I have tried explicitly turning them on in `application.conf`.

This is my `build.sbt`:

```
// core
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  evolutions,
  ehcache,
  ws,
  specs2 % Test,
  guice)

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "4.0.2" % Test

// database
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "4.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "4.0.2"
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4-1201-jdbc41"
```

I have a suspicion that the hook into the React UI is blocking the backend from picking up those files somehow, but have no idea where to start looking. Any help greatly appreciated.

#### Edit:

I'm pretty sure my `application.conf` is set up correctly but here it is:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/standups?user=postgres&password=password"
```

As I said before Im pretty sure this is set up correctly because I can talk to the database. It's just the evolutions that aren't being picked up.

This is my `1.sql`, which resides in `conf/evolutions/default`:

```
-- !Ups

create table person
(
    id       serial       not null primary key,
    name     varchar(255) not null,
    age      smallint     not null
);

-- !Downs

drop table if exists person cascade;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear to me why your evolutions aren't running.

I've tried to emulate your set up in this commit: https://github.com/d6y/scala-play-react-seed/commit/408853bda6f26a7a4fdc49487c2bb00d243ac0dc

...where I had to modify the `FrontendRunHook` to actually start the front-end and the server (via https://github.com/yohangz/scala-play-react-seed/pull/30).

Other than that, `sbt run` started the application and applied the evolution (verified by looking in the database).

I added `play.evolutions.db.default.autoApply = true`, but without that you would have been told the database needs a migration.

I'm also using JDK 8 with this, to avoid a warning relating to Guice (`WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred`). However, you didn't mention you saw that, so that's also probably unrelated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for going to so much effort :)

I cloned your fork and it seemed to work fine, which really puzzled me! Turns out I was being a dufus - I had the script in a folder called `evolutions.default` for some reason, and with "flatten packages" on it looks like two separate folders. Serious facepalm moment!!

Thanks so much for the help though. Knowing it wasn't a setup thing made me switch context and actually find the issue.

Comment: Ouch!  Glad this was useful for figuring it out 

Comment: Thanks @slugmandrew this should be a well-documented pitfall/gotcha! Lost an hour on this

Comment: @kosgeinsky Ha, I'm glad it helped you :D I thought I was pretty stupid when doing it so nice to not be the only one!

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable the play evolutions config parameter

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Evolutions

```
play.evolutions.enabled=true


For example, to enable autoApply for all evolutions, you might set play.evolutions.autoApply=true in application.conf or in a system property. To disable autocommit for a datasource named default, you set play.evolutions.db.default.autocommit=false
```

Comment: Regarding the `play.evolutions.autoApply=true in application.conf` I believe this is only for automatically applying the evolutions, rather than asking the user.

Comment: Evolutions are automatically activated if a database is configured in application.conf and evolution scripts are present. You can disable them by setting play.evolutions.enabled=false

Comment: you need to have the database config in the application.conf otherwise the evolutions will not be enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, have updated the question with some more info. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You'll also need to call `applicationEvolutions` at some point when your project starts up.

Typically that would be done in an instance of `ApplicationLoader`.

This means:

1. adding a class for your application "components", which includes extending `DBComponents with EvolutionsComponents` and accessing `applicationEvolutions`.
2. writing a class that extends `ApplicationLoader` which retuns your components in the `load` method of `ApplicationLoader`.
3. adding the fully qualified class to your `application.conf` as `play.application.loader=your.package.name.here.MyAppLoader`

You can see the outline of the `ApplicationLoader` and components at: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Application-entry-point

The specifics for mixing in the database code to call `applicationEvolutions` is at: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/Evolutions#Enable-evolutions

Comment: Hi Richard. I thought this manual triggering was only required if you want to use compile-time DI - is that right? Previously everything was just wired up for me and worked nicely.

I have given this a go though (slightly different as I don't have access to `DBComponents` due to lacking the `jdbc` dependency in `build.sbt` as it clashes with the slick deps) The issue I have with this seems to be with the Router - I can only get it to compile with `Routes.empty` which isn't much use obviously and the evolutions still don't run.

Comment: fair enough: I only use compile-time DI